# Input disabled after moving object in editor while in "play mode"

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

This is my first question here, i couldn't find an answer online for my problem.
Here it is:
I made a simple script to print some debug info about objects when i press a key. It works as expected unless i first move any of the objects in the scene editor while the game is running.
If i move any of the objects after i hit play it seems that Input.GetKeyDown is ignored after that. I am detecting the input inside the Update function of one of the objects.

```
public GameObject target;
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
    {
        Debug.Log (transform.position);
        Debug.Log (target.transform.position);
    }
}
```

NOTE: this is not the only thing im trying to achieve with my script, but is the simplest case i could build with the same problem.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because when you move the object, the Unity GameView will lose its focus. So just ensure it has the focus again (klick into it), before hitting the key.

Comment: It was just that !!! i can't belive i did not notice that by myself! thanks a lot!

Comment: Hehe, sometimes the solution is simpler, than you can imagine ;-) Or it just needs someone else to look at your problem.